# Java MySql Coumn not found

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

Hy! I am working with JDBC MySql Java project and I am trying to save int values (Id Category) and String values(Name of meal) from my server database in simple java hash map. But every time I try to debugg my code in my hash map are saved only values from last record of specific category meal. For exapmle, in my table "naziv_jela" I have: (name of meal, id_category),greek salad   1, tuna pate    1, marinated anchovies  1, raw sushi    1, black risotto    2, tomato pasta 2, stuffed mushrooms    2, pasta with almonds   2. Each meal has its own ID, his name and id of category, I just wanna save category id and name of meal in hash map, but its always last value of specific category, for example in upper 8 records, it saves only row sushi with ID=1 and pasta with almonds with ID=2 (last values) of each category. I dont know why it saves only last values ??? I need all meals with all categories in my hash map. Here is my code:

```
queryZaJela="SELECT id_kategorija, naziv_hrane FROM `naziv_jela`";
Map <Integer,String>PopisJela = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
                + "localhost:3306/room_service", "root", "");
        Statement Stat = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet Rez = Stat.executeQuery(queryZaJela);

        while (Rez.next()) { 

            PopisJela.put(Rez.getInt("id_kategorija"), Rez.getString("naziv_hrane") );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Map<Integer,Collection<String>>>`

Maps store a *single* value per key, and currently you're just storing one string (the last one you read from the database). You need to store a collection of strings (say, a list), and do something like:

```
if (map.get(id) == null) {
   map.put(id, new ArrayList<String>());
}
map.get(id).add(name);
```

so you first check for an initialised collection for your particular key, and create one if it doesn't exist. *Then* populate the collection as required.

You'll find various open source solutions to this to make your life a bit easier e.g. Google's [MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Answer (score 0):

In you example you are trying to do the following.

Let us consider the results of only category 1.

1, tuna pate 
1, marinated anchovies 
1, raw sushi 
1, black risotto

Before while loop tuna pate PopisJela is empty.

While iterating and putting in the hashmap

PopisJela.put(1, "tuna pate"); // First iteration

PopisJela.put(1, "marinated anchovies"); // second iteration replacing the value "tuna pate" with "marinated anchovies"

PopisJela.put(1, "raw sushi"); // Third iteration replacing the value  "marinated anchovies" with "raw sushi"

PopisJela.put(1, "black risotto"); // fourth and final iteration replacing the value  "raw sushi" with "black risotto"

So, always you will have only the last value in the hashmap PopisJela.

So, in your case create the hashmap in the following way.

Map>> PopisJela = new HashMap>();

...

ResultSet Rez = Stat.executeQuery(queryZaJela);

```
    while (Rez.next()) { 
        if(PopisJela.get(Rez.getInt("id_kategorija") == null){
               List<String> meals = new ArrayList<String>();
               meals.add(Rez.getString("naziv_hrane"));
               PopisJela.put(Rez.getInt("id_kategorija"), meals);

         }else{
               List<String> meals = (List<String>)      PopisJela.get(Rez.getInt("id_kategorija"));
               meals.add(Rez.getString("naziv_hrane"));
        }
    }
```

...